# Creating a tool that can break certain blocks as a command in Bedrock 1.14

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been trying to figure out a way to create a tool that can only break certain blocks, but I found nothing for bedrock 1.14 update?

I looked at other questions but none seem to work, since they reference Java Edition, or potentially that the command has changed for the new update (1.14) so is there an updated version?